# resample and sum by other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wish to `resample` by `1D` if column `sell` is `False` and `sum` column `amount`.

Here is my data:

```
id          date            price   amount      sell
23688927    1472688031000   576.27  0.8         false
23688933    1472688054000   576.26  0.020847    true
23688945    1472688144000   576.27  0.14514252  false
23688949    1472688144000   576.27  0.38154176  false
```

The following code filters correctly, I just can't figure out how to `sum` by mentioned column.

```
df.loc[:, 'timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'date'], unit='ms')
df.index = df.timestamp
(df['sell'] == 0).resample('1D')
```

Reading some article this should work, I get 'Column not found: amount'`

```
(df['sell'] == 0).resample('1D')['amount'].sum()
```

Comment: seems odd since to resample you need a date like index and yours seems to be 'id'

Comment: Sorry, will update the question.

Comment: still not valid since there is no dfTrades in your example

Comment: Finished editing.

Comment: @krizajb what should the output be for your example? Are you only including the where `sell` is `false` or including all amounts as long as one sell is `false` for that sample?

Comment: the last line of your code is almost what you needed, you're creating a series of booleans with the result of the comparison between the contents of series 'sell' and 'False'. You need to get the dataframe slice based on the result of that boolean series and then call the resample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
(df[df['sell'] == 0]).resample('1D').amount.sum()
```

Output:

```
timestamp
2016-09-01    1.347531
```

Comment: U forgot the `sell ==0` filter. I get `'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'amount'`

Comment: Yeah I saw, couldn't reply with "ok" comment, so I just waited for the update :) Testing!

Comment: I added a comment on your question explaining what was missing on your attempts, hope it helps